# How to return subdocuments from an object in an array with Meteor and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, meteor

This is a followup question from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37694598/484732) here on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Firstly, Thanks to [@David Weldon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635981/david-weldon): I was able to structure my update properly.  However when I go to get the output from the database the object I added to `score` seams to be missing.

Maybe this is the default behavior of `db.ideas.find()`.  I expected to also get the subdocuments when I performed the `db.ideas.find()`.

Code I ran:

```
Ideas.update("bKXXrpYmppFBfq9Kx", {
  $addToSet: {
    score: { userId: "W9YEs84QFhZzJeB6j", score: 1 },
    votedOnBy: "W9YEs84QFhZzJeB6j"
  },
  $inc: {
    overallScore: 1,
    timesVotedOn: 1
  }
});
```

Output from mongo db console:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.ideas.find()
{
    "_id" : "bKXXrpYmppFBfq9Kx",
    "title" : "Jump through the portal",
    "body" : "The elves from Eldernland should jump through the blue portal mentioned in episode one.",
    "userId" : "W9YEs84QFhZzJeB6j",
    "author" : "Nate Beck",
    "episodeId" : "LbDynnAHxAgM5PPXM",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-06-07T20:37:05.775Z"),
    "votedOnBy" : [
        "W9YEs84QFhZzJeB6j"
    ],
    "timesVotedOn" : 3,
    "score" : [
        {

        }
    ],
    "overallScore" : 1
}
```

I was expecting to see what was in "Score" this looks like an empty object.

Any ideas what is going on wrong here?

Comment: `.find()` and `.findOne()` format slightly differently in the meteor mongo console, try the latter. Or try `db.ideas.findOne(id).score`

Comment: @Jeremy I suspect you are just seeing documents inserted by previous attempts and/or you are inserting from more than one place. If this is a dev environment, try just doing `db.ideas.remove({})` and then starting the app again (or do `meteor reset`). Also see [common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) for find vs findOne vs fetch within meteor.

Comment: [@Michel Floyd](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2805154/michel-floyd): Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it, with no luck.  Here is the [output of my console:](https://git.io/vom7c) https://git.io/vom7c

Comment: [@David Weldon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/635981/david-weldon): Thank you also for your suggestion. I reset the database and had the update run from the fixtures.js file. Everything works perfectly - except the score array object (again, same problem). I have [a gist I created for you](https://git.io/vom5H) to show you the output of the console, and I included the fixture.js there also. Here's the gist: https://git.io/vom5H

I also read your blog post and found it most informative, thank you for writing that and sharing it with me. Although it didn't answer this question, I enjoyed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## !SOLVED!

The problem here is that I was unaware what the package [aldeed:collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) was doing to my code.  I added this package to use [OrionJS](http://www.orionjs.org) (here's the [github page](https://github.com/orionjs/orion)).  And I didn't notice that this [aldeed:collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) was forcing validation on all of my updates.  I was running into this before, but it was giving me an error.  In the past I was able to trace the error down.  This time, there was **no error** anywhere.  It would update the array, but with an empty object.  So confusing.  I'm going to post an issue on [aldeed:collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2)'s project page.

From the [project documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2): "[[aldeed:collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) is a] Meteor package that allows you to attach a schema to a Mongo.Collection. **Automatically validates against that schema when inserting and *updating*** from client or server code."

The [documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#subobjects-and-arrays-of-objects) for the correction can be found [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#subobjects-and-arrays-of-objects).

---

## Solution:

Because I'm using [aldeed:simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) and [aldeed:collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#subobjects-and-arrays-of-objects) I need to make sure to attach a proper "Schema" to my collection.

Like So:

```
Ideas.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  // ... a bunch of other schema data

  // I was missing this:
  score: {
    type: [Object],
    optional: true,
    label: 'Score',
  },
  "score.$.userId": {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    label: 'Score'
  },
  "score.$.score": {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    label: 'Score'
  }

  // ... a bunch more schema data
});
```

---

## Troubleshooting:

How did I figure this out?

Well, I'm new to MongoDB - so I was reluctant to go to the console and just try to do the update from there.  In fact, this didn't even occur to me until I was talking with my wife.

I tried everything, adding quotes around ***everything***, looking at other people's code.  I checked out all of MongoDB's excellent documentation.  I looked at youtube videos.  I looked at other stackoverflow.com solutions.  Finally it occurred to me that everyone else's code looks exactly like my code, and this should just WORK.  I even signed up on [Clarity.fm](https://clarity.fm/) to ask a question from [Sacha Greif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649299/sacha) for $1 a minute.

... I was beginning to think that my mongo database wasn't working.  Perhaps ***my mongo*** install was broken?

So, okay, there is a test for that... After two days of this torture it finally came to me - Just try the update in the mongo console... (duh)

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.ideas.update({_id:"DqEGjK3xSTBdpEgXa"}, {$addToSet: {score: {userId: "123456", score: 1}}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
meteor:PRIMARY> db.ideas.find()
{
  "_id" : "DqEGjK3xSTBdpEgXa",
  "title" : "Revive Randolf With Bloodmagic",
  "body" : "Bring Randolf back from the dead using witche's bloodmagic.",
  "userId" : "Rz28ByKYM4Y8futFb",
  "author" : "Iryna Iglehart",
  "episodeId" : "iQaxyLPi5iaYtQngf",
  "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-06-08T17:37:57.237Z"),
  "score" : [
    {
      "userId" : "123456",
      "score" : 1
    }
  ],
  "overallScore" : 0,
  "votedOnBy" : [ ],
  "timesVotedOn" : 0
}
```

Once I knew that mongo COULD do my update - I ***knew*** the problem had to be with my meteor setup.  I would have found a issue on meteor by now if this was a problem.  I searched every dark corner of google trying to figure this one out.

It wasn't long before I remembered I was having *weird* validation issues before.  Except these validation issues always came with an error.  The fact that there was no error and the array was simply updated with empty objects really threw me for a loop.

---

## What I Learned:

1. If at first meteor fails, try the mongo console...
2. As per [@David Weldon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635981/david-weldon)'s comment - another good debugging technique which would have helped me, which I could have tried a long time ago is to start a fresh meteor project and test my code out there, then add packages one at a time and see when it/if any of them break the code.  This test would have pointed out that fundamentally the code was correct, and only needed the attached schema because of an added package.
3. Don't blindly add packages.  Understand if/when packages change the flow of development such as [aldeed:collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2)

---

## Thank you:

A BIG THANKS to [@Michel Floyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2805154/michel-floyd) and [@David Weldon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635981/david-weldon) for all your help on this problem.

---

## Important Links:

1. I learned quite a bit from [common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) written by [@David Weldon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635981/david-weldon)
2. The [documentation for aldeed:collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#subobjects-and-arrays-of-objects)
3. The [documentation for aldeed:simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema)
4. Search for "Finding Data" on [this meteor tutorial](http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/databases-part-1/) - it talks about fetch() and how it is helpful.  This helped me during my troubleshooting on this problem.
5. Reviewing the [documentation on about update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) from MongoDB
6. [MongoDB $addToSet Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)
7. [MongoDB $push Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)
8. [MongoDB Bios Example Collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bios-example-collection/] - It was after looking at documents like this that I really figured out there is nothing wrong with my database design, there SHOULD have been a way to do this all along (and there is, obviously)

---

## Related Question:

[[Solved] How to Update An Array of Subdocuments on a MongoDB Collection in MeteorJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37692323/how-to-update-an-array-of-subdocuments-on-a-mongodb-collection-in-meteorjs)

Comment: Nice write-up. Another important debugging technique is to start with an empty project and add things until it fails to work correctly. In this case, a one-file app without collection2 would have demonstrated the code was fundamentally correct.

Comment: [@David Weldon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/635981/david-weldon): Thank you so much - you're right.  Funny thing, I created a project to answer someone else's problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37692455/484732) - I did this mainly for clarity for him.  But now that you say that I realize I could have done that for myself also but in my case as a debugging technique.  I'm new to meteor (as you can tell).  Thank you so much for all of your time and attention.